# How to switch on another tabItem in tabBar controller in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

I am using Xcode 11.3.1, Swift 5. I made tabBarController with MainStoryBoard. Now I want to move on third item(another view controller) from first item(shown view controller), on click on button as shown in figure.

[image]

How to do I that?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that

```
//MARK:- if you are in UITabBarController 
self.selectedIndex = 2
```

or

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

Comment: It is not working for me actually. Nothing happens on button's click

Comment: are you trying to do that in cell ?

Comment: I took a button in cell.

Comment: you need to do that from controller instead of cell ... use closure or delegate for that to trigger function in controller and then call this .. in that function

Comment: Yes I am doing same. I am using delegate and trigger function in controller file.  As,  func onClickButton(index: Int) {
                    tabBar.selectedIndex = 2  
    }